# How to get the opposite property?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object with (always) 2 properties. It wil always have 2 properties. 3 properties won't be possible:

```
var people = {
   'John': { ... },
   'Peter': { ... }
}
```

And I have the variable `var name = 'John'`.

Is there a simple way to get the value of property `'Peter'` when the value of `name` is `'John'`?
Without hard-coding it with the names John en Peter. So the functionality must get the opposite property of the value in variable `name`

Comment: What happens if there are three properties? Which one is the "opposite?

Comment: There wil always be 2 properties. 3 properties won't be possible.

Comment: It's Javascript, of course it's possible.

Comment: Other parts of my code covers the fact that it can't have 3 properties.

Comment: Hint: get a list of the properties. From that, get the name of the property that is not the one you have. Get the value of that property.

Comment: It's probably time to write a data structure class that does the work you need, instead of a plain object, so you can do `myobj.getOther("john")` and get "whatever is the property that isn't John". No reason to have the code that needs to work with the data _also_ be responsible for the selection logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` will give you an array of the property names.

`filter` lets you filter that array.

So:

```js
const name = "John";
const people = {
  'John': 1,
  'Peter': 1
};
const [result] = Object.keys(people).filter(person => person !== name);

console.log({
  result
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let name = 'John'; // or whatever
let names = Object.keys(people);

let otherName = names.find(n => n !== name);
people[otherName] // this gives you the value of the other name's property
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple function, that does this. It takes a key, and an object. It returns the value of the element in the given object by the inverse key of the given key. This will only work if the object only has two keys.

```
var people = {
    'John': { 'b':[3,4] },
    'Peter': { 'a':[1,2] }
}
getInverseObjectElem = (key,object) => { // Define function 'getInverseObjectElem'
    listOfObjectKeys = Object.keys(object) // Create an array of the object keys
    inverseKey = listOfObjectKeys.filter(k => k != key)[0] // filter the list of keys, and get the first key that doesnt match the given key.
    return object[inverseKey] // Return the value in the object, by the inverseKey
}
console.log(getInverseObjectElem('John',people))
```

Comment: nice thanks! BTW you can also use just `object.keys()` as an array of the object's keys. something like: `inverseKey = object.keys().filter(k => k != key)[0]`

Comment: Yeah, I figured there was probably a better way. Although I feel like this explains the whole process. I'll clean it up a bit more :D

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```js
for (let key in people){
    if (key != name) return people[key];
}
```